# Generating JSON from a query

Tags: javascript, json, coldfusion

I am trying to generate JSON from a query. All this seems to be too much grinding it out.

```
string function getJSON() output="false"    {   

  var result = "[";
  var myrow = 0;

  for(var row in this.qryLocation)  {
    myrow++;
    result &= "[" 
             & row.LocationID                     & ',' 
             & '"' & row.Address & " " & row.City & '",' 
             & '"' & row.formatted_CreateDate     & '"'
             & ']' 
             & myRow < this.qryLocation.recordcount ? ',' : ''; 
    } // end for-in query

  return result & "]";  
  }
```

All this seems very hard to read, especially making sure that the last row does not get an extra comma.

Comment: That does seem quite clunky. I'm sure someone will have ideas on making this more readable and practical.

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion?

Comment: It's difficult to answer well without knowing your version of CF, but as a practice: don't build a JSON string by hand: build a native data structure which represents the format you need, then serialise it to JSON when done.

Comment: I am on ColdFusion 11

Comment: The data comes from the result of a CFquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with [Adam's comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/102551/generating-json-from-a-query#comment187911_102551). Generally, you should avoid rolling-your-own JSON. Just create native CF objects as usual (ie CF arrays and structures). Then use `SerializeJSON` to generate the JSON string.

`SerializeJSON` eliminates the need for manual quoting, which dramatically improves the readability of the code IMO. It also handles any escaping of object values automatically (the current code does not). Granted, [Adobe's `SerializeJSON` function does have a few .. "quirks"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Abugbase.adobe.com%20serializejson%20ColdFusion). So you may prefer to use a different implementation. However, the basic approach remains the same.

```
string function getJSON() output="false"    {    
  var result = [];

  for(var row in this.qryLocation)  {
    arrayAppend(result, [ row.LocationID, row.Address & " " & row.City, row.formatted_CreateDate ] );
  } 

  return serializeJSON(result);  
}
```